# Visual studio show (The project file could not be loaded) for any new Class Library Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio

When I attempt to create any class library project in Visual Studio Express 2013 I receive the following message:

> The project file could not be loaded. ",hexadecimal value 0x1F, is an
>   invalid character. Line 1, position 1. C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\12.0\bin\Microsoft.ServiceModel.Targets

[Image of error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfvQb.jpg)

Is there any packages can I install it to fix this issue.

Comment: have you tried googling the exact error to see what it yields..?

Comment: Do you have a Perforce client installed? Search online for this error messages suggests this is caused by Perforce.